# Keep row that the element is closest to 0 in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to keep rows with a condition. There are two columns in my sample dataframe. Name column contains duplicated names and the Day column contains days in timedelta64[ns].

df

```
Name     Day
Andrew   23 days
Andrew   5 days
Andrew   -345 days
Andrew   84 days
Bess     2 days
Bess     -83 days
Bess     -123 days
Derek    344 days
Derek    238 days
Leslie   47 days
Leslie   543 days
Leslie   134 days
Leslie   -3 days
```

The operation would keep the element Day column that is closest to 0 by each name in the Name column.

Desired df

```
Name     Day
Andrew   5 days
Bess     2 days
Derek    238 days
Leslie   -3 days
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Since the aim is to look for values closed to 0, get the [absolute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) value of each entry in the `Day` column, look for the [minimum index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) and get the values on those indices. The idea is from a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62295885/7175713) by [@Ch3ster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster)

```
df.groupby("Name").agg(lambda x: x[x.abs().idxmin()])

Name
Andrew      5
Bess        2
Derek     238
Leslie     -3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) value of column `Day` and use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to group the column on `Name` and use aggregation function [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) to get the indices of values closest to `zero`, finally use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the indices to thie corresponding `timedelta` values:

```
s = df['Day'].abs().groupby(df['Name']).idxmin().map(df['Day'])
```

Result:

```
# print(s)

Name
Andrew     5 days
Bess       2 days
Derek    238 days
Leslie    -3 days
Name: Day, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way. `groupby()` name, find absolute difference, and select smallest using `nsmallest(1)`

```
 df.groupby('Name')['Day'].apply(lambda x: abs(x).nsmallest(1))



Name      
Andrew  1      5 days
Bess    4      2 days
Derek   8    238 days
Leslie  12     3 days
```

Comment: Why `abs((0-x))` instead of just `abs(x)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this, assuming that your data frame is called `df`. The solution is still valid, even if you have more columns in your data frame.

```
import numpy as np

(df
 .assign(Diff_from_0=np.abs(df['Day']-0))  # assign a temporary column for the calculations
 .sort_values('Diff_from_0')  # sort values by our temporary column (ascending)
 .groupby(level=0)  # group by the index (names)
 .head(1)  # get first row (lowest diff from 0) for each unique index value
 .sort_index()  # sort the data frame by index, so that you get the same order of names
 .drop(columns='Diff_from_0')  # drop the temporary column, we do not need it anymore
)
```

For the sake of completeness, I created `df` in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': [23, 5, -345, 84, 2, -83, -123, 344, 238, 47, 543, 134, -3]}, 
                 index=['Andrew', 'Andrew', 'Andrew', 'Andrew', 'Bess', 'Bess', 'Bess', 'Derek', 'Derek', 'Leslie', 'Leslie', 'Leslie', 'Leslie'])
```